# Generate code from properties file

Tags: java, c#, eclipse, resourcebundle

Coming from C# background, I'm used to creating a resource file `Resources.resx` in Visual Studio. This generates a class in the background and I can access resoures by `Resources.ResourceName`, which has some benefits

- it provides auto completion ("Intellisense")
- it generates a compiler error if a resource is renamed (instead of a runtime error)
- I can use "Find usages" to check where the same resource is used again

AFAIK, the equivalent to a *RESX* file in Java is a *Properties* file. I can access a resource using `ResourceBundle.getBundle("filename").getString("resourcename");`. As you can see, the filename and the resource name are strings and

- I don't have auto completion
- I get runtime errors instead of compiler errors
- I need to do a generic text search to find other usages which is not very reliable

I strongly doubt that I'm the first person who wants all the additional benefits of generated code, so

**How can I generate classes from properties files in Eclipse and use it like in C#?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [jlibs](http://jlibs.in) library. see tutorial [Internationalization made easier](http://jlibs.in/i18n/Internationalization.html). BTW I am the owner of this project;

this library provides compile time safety and uses annotations at compile time to generate java code

Comment: That's definitely interesting. I did not fully understand how resources will be translated. Example: `@Message("Execute")` is only an English text. How does it know that this is English? And how do I add a German text?

Comment: in annotations you give english text only. for other languages you add Bundle_jp.properties for japanese

Comment: I think I got it. The compiler generates the generic .properties file only. Then I add every other language manually and that won't be touched by the compiler. I'll give it a try and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: yes. ideally, the translators are comfortable in editing properties file. they dont like to add annotations with specific languages in source code.

Comment: I'm making progress. It compiles the interface to a resource and I can use it with the default text. But the resource is in the `bin` folder. IMHO I need it in the `resources` folder and add it to SVN. I'll continue tomorrow.

Comment: Another question is: since I only call a method, how can I specify the locale which is used for the translation? I need to switch the locale at runtime.

Comment: You can do Locale.setDefault(..); i know it is not good suggestion; I will add that support

Answer (score 1):

Civilian framework contains a [generator tool](http://www.civilian-framework.org/doc-l10n.html#rescompiler) to manage resource bundles and generate a class which contains constants for all entries in the resource bundle.

The steps to use it are the following:

1. You maintain a Excel file, first column contains the resource key, next columns translations in the target languages. Such a Excel can easily be given to translators.
2. Whenever you have changed this Excel file you run the ResBundleCompiler (a simple command-line tool). The compiler reads the excel file and generates a ResourceBundle properties file for every language and a class which defines constants for every resource key
3. In your application you use the constants instead of a literal strings to refer to resource keys, giving all the advantages you described.

Comment: Also nice. I prefer to not have the additional overhead of using an Excel file, since I don't pass the translations to an office. I'm working with Resource Bundle Editor directly in Eclipse.

Comment: The tool could surely be extended to read an existing property file and just generate the constants class. Thanks for pointing to the C# stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is an XML format and then use JAXB in JDK to create strongly typed object out of it. Specifically look at javax.xml.bind.JAXB

To see an example of how to generate classes directly from XML Schema read this: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071784/enterprise-java/java-xml-mapping-made-easy-with-jaxb-2-0.html

The JAXB binding compiler lets you generate Java classes from a given XML schema. The JAXB binding compiler transforms an XML schema into a collection of Java classes that match the structure described in the XML schema. These classes are annotated with special JAXB annotations, which provide the runtime framework with the mappings it needs to process the corresponding XML documents.

The binding runtime framework provides an efficient and easy-to-use mechanism for unmarshalling (or reading) and marshalling (or writing) XML documents. It lets you transform an XML document into a hierarchy of Java objects (unmarshalling) or, inversely, transform a Java object hierarchy into XML format (marshalling).